# textbox password gets shown on alert message

Tags: c#, asp.net

My textbox HTML code is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_pass" 
             runat="server" class="txt-box_reg" 
             onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') 
                     {
                        this.value = '';this.type='password';
                     }" 
             onblur="if (this.value == '') 
                     {
                        this.value = 'Password';this.type='text';
                     }" 
             value="Password"> 
</asp:TextBox>
```

and my javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function myFocus(element) {
        if (element.value == element.defaultValue) {
            element.value = '';
        }
    }
    function myBlur(element) {
        if (element.value == '') {
            element.value = element.defaultValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

All things work fine till the alert message box opens on my page.
When the alert message opens, the password shows and when I close the alert box the password regain its value as...

**//More INFORMATION//**

[image]

When I put `textmode="password"` then the second textbox shows but I use to show my textbox as 3rd textbox **i.e. Confirm Password**

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why aren't you using textbox with textmode as password

Comment: @tariq please check my edited question again

Comment: @MiteshJain still can't get it, what are u trying to achieve with confirm password textbox ?

Comment: if i give textmode="password" than i will get dot sign but i want in inside textbox written as Password

Comment: where is the "alert message" code

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo my alert message comes through javascript ..............................................................
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("<%=txt_pass.ClientID%>").value == "Password" || document.getElementById("<%=txt_pass.ClientID%>").value == "") {
                alert("Required Password");
                document.getElementById("<%=txt_pass.ClientID%>").focus();
                return false; }...............................................................

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo make try some alert box or any kind of error box show after you write password

Comment: i would recommend you also post the code where the alert box came

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing, try it in your source code.

```
if(your alert box condition)
{
    //your alert box coding
    txt_pass.Text = ""; // or make text as you wish.
}
else.....
```

do this in your .cs page, at where you popup your Alert-box.

Comment: This is one of the way. If you find out any other solution then also tell me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to it using jQuery:

```
$(".txt-box_reg").focus(function (pas) {
  $(".txt-box_reg").attr("Type", "Password");
});
```